# Get DIV id on hover/click

Tags: jquery, html

I need to get the id of a DIV on click or hover to use when clicking on the DIV to go to a URL.

This is what I have so far...

```js
$('.div1').mouseover(function() {
  var thisdiv = this.id;
});

$('.div1').click(function() {
  var divclick = document.getElementById(thisdiv);
  divclick.style.cursor = 'pointer';
  divclick.onclick = function() {
    window.location.href = "displayadvert.php?a=" + thisdiv;
  };
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div1" id="1">ONE</div>
<div class="div1" id="2">TWO</div>
<div class="div1" id="3">THREE</div>
```

Comment: Numeric `ID` is not valid!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `this.id` in the click function:

```js
$('.div1').click(function() {
 console.log(this.id);
 window.location.href = "displayadvert.php?a="+this.id;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div1" id="1">ONE</div>
<div class="div1" id="2">TWO</div>
<div class="div1" id="3">THREE</div>
```

Comment: $('.div1').click(function() { window.location.href = "displayadvert.php?a="+this.id;})  Thank you. I just tried this but it does nothing on click?

Comment: Should do, hit "run code snippet" and give it a go (even though it will 404 it should change the url)

Comment: Ok your code works, thank you. I just had to move the JQuery further down on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Here's solution -

```js
function goToSomeUrl(event) {
    console.log(event.target.id); 
}

$('.div1').mouseover(goToSomeUrl);
$('.div1').click(goToSomeUrl);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div1" id="1">ONE</div>
<div class="div1" id="2">TWO</div>
<div class="div1" id="3">THREE</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, much appreciated.